# Result from RSS feed with cURL via PHP is different than cURL via console (first delivers some url list and second delivers the expected XML)

Tags: php, xml, rss

I'm trying to get an old page to run again and it seems that with the change from http to https on that URL = https://feeds.bbci.co.uk/news/politics/rss.xml curl via PHP isn't delivering the XML anymore. After some research I got the `curl_setopt_array` pimped up like this:

```
function curl_get($url) {
    
    $client = curl_init();
    curl_setopt_array($client, array(
      CURLOPT_URL => $url,
      CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
      CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
      CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
      CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => false,
      CURLOPT_HEADER => true,
      CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
      CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => ['Accept: application/xml'],
      CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
      CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'GET',
      CURLOPT_USERAGENT => 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.124 Safari/537.36',
    ));
    
    $response = curl_exec($client);
    
    curl_close($client);
    return $response;
    }
```

The response after I do `curl_get` is a long list of URLs like you see below. Before I'm echoing out the response I'm splitting it into header and xml part after the `curl_get($url);`:

```
list($headers, $xml) = explode("\r\n\r\n", $response, 2);
echo "Response Headers: \n" . $headers . "\n";
echo "\nXML Content: \n" . $xml;

Response Headers:
HTTP/1.1 200 OK Server: Belfrage belfrage-cache-status: HIT bsig: 48f765c294080d8b70a116081be96156 Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8 Content-Encoding: gzip brequestid: fe2daa111e8d4f6ea0584f542e09bcf1 x-content-type-options: nosniff bid: cedric req-svc-chain: BELFRAGE Content-Length: 10737 Cache-Control: public, max-age=73 Date: Wed, 28 Feb 2024 05:35:15 GMT Connection: keep-alive Vary: Accept-Encoding Timing-Allow-Origin: https://www.bbc.co.uk, https://www.bbc.com

XML Content:
https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/ 
https://news.bbcimg.co.uk/nol/shared/img/bbc_news_120x60.gif
https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/ RSS for Node Fri, 23 Feb 2024 08:12:42 GMT15
https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/uk-politics-68377243?at_medium=RSS&at_campaign=KARANGA
https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/uk-politics-68377243 Fri, 23 Feb 2024
07:12:03 GMT[...]
```

As you can see the XML part of the response is no XML, it is a long list of URLs. If I curl the same URL in the console though I get a proper XML as expected (I also see in the source of the page that it actually is XML).

After CBroes input, I extended the config array for the call with this option `CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => ['Accept: application/xml'],`. Though it didn't change anything in the output.

Any ideas?

Comment: I don't see any redirect happening. This is probably rather an issue of different response formats being delivered, based on what `Accept` request header the client sends.

Comment: What do you do with the response? Are you sure it's not XML?

Comment: Whilst the BBC did change the format of their RSS feed urls a few months ago if you `view source` you'll see the actual XML

Comment: @CBroe, thanks for the tip with the `HTTPHEADER` though adding 
`CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => ['Accept: application/xml'],` to the config array  didn't change anything in the output. :(

@Olivier the response is posted there ^. I only get the header of the file and no XML

Comment: What initial URL are you actually calling this function with? Is that `https://feeds.bbci.co.uk/news/politics/rss.xml`, or something else? I just tried that one with three different "redirect checker" services, and all three said they got a 200 response, without _any_ redirects. What you have shown after `Response Headers:` - is that supposed to be the output of several of those `echo($location);` headers, or something else?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, the check for the httpCode lockup was put by me when the program was still querying the original URL`http://feeds.bbci.co.uk/news/politics/rss.xml` (http). I removed the lookup part from the code and updated the output accordingly.